# How to store a hidden string with a UITableViewCell?

Tags: xcode, swift3

I want to attach information (a string) to each UITableViewCell when populating TableView with UITableViewCells. I don't want it to be visible- I just need to access this string when the row/cell is selected. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried? You'll get more and better answers If you show what you've tried, and demonstrate that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself. Without that people may be unwilling to help. See [Ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best choice is probably to subclass `UITableViewCell` and add a string property. This can then be assigned either as a constant, or when setting up your cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var customString = "Default"
}

--------

func cellForRow(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "identifier", indexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    cell.customString = "String"
    return cell
}

func didSelectRow(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell: CustomCell = tableView.cellForRow(atIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {
        return
    }
    let stringFromCell = cell.customString
}
```

The above has not been compiled, so may not work word for word, but you get the principle.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a property `selected` to your model.
- In `cellForRow` show/hide the string depending on the state of `selected`.
- In `didSelectRow` toggle `selected` in the model and reload the row.